# Sorting products in Spree admin panel by 'created_at' field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to display additional column (`created_at`) in 'Products' tab in my Spree admin panel. I have done it using deface similarly to [the standard `name` and `master price` columns](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/backend/app/views/spree/admin/products/index.html.erb#L60). The deface adding the header with sortable link to the table looks like this:

```
Deface::Override.new(
    virtual_path: 'spree/admin/products/index',
    name:         'created_at_column_header_in_products',
    insert_before: "[data-hook='admin_products_index_header_actions']"
    text: "
        <th class='text-center'>
            <%= sort_link @search, 'created_at', Spree.t(:created_at) %>
        </th>
    "
)
```

I can click the "CREATED AT" link and the url that gets queried then is

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/products?q%5Bdeleted_at_null%5D=1&q%5Bs%5D=created_at+asc
```

However, I can see no SQL query in the console, that would order the products by `created_at` (while sorting by name produces SQL queries ordering by name) and the results in admin panel indeed seem unsorted.

Why my solution doesn't work?

EDIT:

I tried every field from `spree_products` table and the only ones that worked with this deface override were `name` and `slug`. What does this thing depend on?

Comment: Ok, So you meant you are getting the request from browser to correct controller, Right ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes. The request is sent to the `Spree::Admin::ProductsController#index` action, if that's what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I found that there is something like `whitelisted_ransackable_attributes` in the `Spree::Product` model and it had only `slug` attribute. I have overwritten it in a decorator:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do  
  self.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes = %w[slug created_at]
end
```